# Remove markers/bubbles in OSM

Tags: android, openstreetmap, marker, osmdroid, infobubble

I have a map with OverlayItems, when I want to clean my map I do this.

```
mapView.getOverlays().clear();
```

But the problem is when I have a bubble/InfoWindow of my OverlayItems open. It cleans all except for the bubble.
What should I do?
Thanks

**Edit:** In OSMdroid

Comment: You didn't mention the library/framework you are using.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution. I have been seeing my class OverlayWithBubble and I have a method removeAllItems(). This is my method.

```
    @Override
    public synchronized void removeAllItems(){
            super.removeAllItems();
            hideBubble();
    }
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, what code does your hideBubble(); method contain?